# How does one use FbTransactionOptions / TransactionBehavior to implement a wait?

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird, firebird-embedded

How does one use FbTransactionOptions / TransactionBehavior to implement a Wait?

I have found some info about using FbTransactionOptions / TransactionBehavior, but not enough details to implement.

```
string stCmd = "UPDATE " + stTableName + " SET " + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID[0] + " = @p0";
for (int iii = 1; iii < liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count(); iii++)
    stCmd += ", " + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID[iii] + " = @p" + iii.ToString();
stCmd += " WHERE" + stFieldKeyID + "= @p" + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count().ToString();

FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
new FbTransactionOptions()
{
    TransactionBehavior = FbTransactionBehavior.Concurrency | 
                          FbTransactionBehavior.Wait
}; 

using (FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(stCmd, fbConn, fbTransaction)) {
    for (int iii = 0; iii < liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count(); iii++) {
        string stPlaceHolder = "@p" + (iii).ToString();
        string stValue = liststNewValuesNoKeyID[iii];
        fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(stPlaceHolder, stValue);
    }
    int iKeyID = Convert.ToInt32(stKeyID);
    fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count().ToString(), iKeyID);
    fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    fbTransaction.Commit();
```

In the above example, TransactionBehavior is not used.  Rearranging causes the compiler to complain.

```
new FbTransactionOptions()
{
    TransactionBehavior = FbTransactionBehavior.Concurrency | 
                          FbTransactionBehavior.Wait
};
FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction(TransactionBehavior);
```

Also, how does one set the value of Wait?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`FbConnection.BeginTransaction(FbTransactionOptions options)`](https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/Provider/src/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/FirebirdClient/FbConnection.cs#L341). And you need to pass it the instance of `FbTransactionOptions` you created, so:

```
var transactionOptions = new FbTransactionOptions()
{
    TransactionBehavior = FbTransactionBehavior.Concurrency | 
                          FbTransactionBehavior.Wait
}; 
FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction(transactionOptions);
```

Your original code didn't work because you only created an instance of `FbTransactionOptions` and immediately threw it away. The second attempt didn't work, because you don't have `TransactionBehavior` anywhere (it is a property of `FbTransactionOptions`, not a thing on its own).

Comment: How do I set the value of Wait?

Comment: @ttom property `WaitTimeout` on `FbTransactionOptions`. Do you know that you can discover a lot of these things in Visual Studio?

Comment: I am unable to find relevant info about FbTransactionOptions FbTransactionBehavior.Wait / WaitTimeout on StackOverflow or MSDN forums.

Comment: @ttom I was referring to auto-completion suggesting properties. MSDN naturally won't provide documentation on a non-Microsoft product. I agree that there is not a lot of documentation for the Firebird ado.net provider, but that means that you have to dig a little deeper.

Comment: Two people accessing the same record simultaneously could happen.  I suspect there is a standard way people handle this occasional occurrence.  It's surprising to find no postings about this.

Comment: @ttom This is usually solved with a form of optimisitic concurrency: you don't lock the table, but will only notice on update, eg because you use something like `update ..., lastupdate = current_timestamp where lastupdated = <lastupdated when read>`, if no record was updated, there was a conflict and the user needs to redo the work. For some suggestion about pessimistic locking, see [How to Lock a Record in InterBase/Firebird](https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/how_to/doc_109). This [tutorial](https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/firebird-tutorial-210.html) also has explanations.